# Open a .accdb file in sas enterprise miner

Tags: sas, business-intelligence, data-analysis

I have to perform data prediction using SAS Enterprise Miner. SAS only has an option to load a SAS table but the problem is i have a database with two tables that i have to use for the prediction. How do i get the two tables from the database into SAS Enterprise Miner.

Comment: Just to be clear, this is an Access database you're talking about (an .accdb or .mdb file)?

Comment: .MDF file is a SQL Server filetype, not an Access filetype.

Comment: oh yes sorry, my bad.

Comment: I find it unlikely that SAS has a direct way to use a .mdf file.  You likely need to mount it in SQL Server first.

Comment: how about a .mdb file is it also just as tricky to open?

Comment: An .mdb file is an access database. Entirely different thing. That may be directly supported. (I don't know EM - only base SAS - but that is usable in base SAS. )

Comment: The only solution i could find was to read the files in base SAS and save them as .sas7bat files in a library

Answer (score 0):

I have not used Access or Miner in 10 years.  However, I would suggest something like:

Does Access have the concept of a view?  If so, then create the view in Access and then just use that.

or

Write a stand alone piece of code that pulls the tables from Access and does the join in SAS.  I believe you can do this in Miner.  If not, just do it in Enterprise Guide and save the table to a location you can pick it up with Miner.

or

Create a SAS view from the Access database that does the join and use that in Miner. Same as above, just save a view instead of a table -- allows you to update the Access database without having to recreate the table.

Comment: I think the OP is asking how to connect the access database to SAS at all.

Comment: I gotcha.  Over thought this one!

Comment: Thanks guys i found a solution, i posted it here.

Answer (score 0):

After looking into this problem I finally decided to use base SAS to read the database and extract the individual tables, save them into a SAS library, in that way they will be saved on the local drive then i could use them in Enterprise Miner.

```
/*Create a new library to store converted files*/
libname db 'C:\\Users\\Documents\\Data Sources';

/*import the first table from the database into the newly created library*/
proc import out = db.Table1
datatable = 'Table1'
dbms= ACCESS Replace;
database= "C:\\Users\\Documents\\Data Sources\\DBName.mdb";
usedate=yes;
scantime=no;
dbsaslabel=none;
run;

/*import the second table from the database into the newly created library*/
proc import out = db.Table2
datatable = 'Table2'
dbms= ACCESS Replace;
database= "C:\\Users\\Documents\\Data Sources\\DBName.mdb";
usedate=yes;
scantime=no;
dbsaslabel=none;
run;
```